# SQLDeveloper Spool to user profile

Tags: sql, oracle-sqldeveloper, user-profile, spool

I'm building a powershell script that will execute a SQL query and spool result to a csv. This file is afterwards read and other actions will be made.
I would like to spool in the User Profile directory of the user who runs the script.

Now i''ve hardcoded my directory and works fine.

```
spool C:\users\<username>\documents\cutoff.csv REP
```

but i'm not sure I've rights to save a file in any other directory on the HD.

I thought that would be something like this

```
spool %userprofiledirectory%\cutoff.csv
```

like in windows powershell there is the command

```bsh
[Environment]::GetFolderPath('MyDocuments')
```

Comment: I just discovered that sqlplus always writes to the current working directory unless you give it a fully qualified filename to write to.
So if you do a CD Your_Directory and after you run a script with SQLPLUS, it spools in the directory you moved just before!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using SQLcl or SQL Developer, then just use the CD command to set your current working directory - this will be used for both looking for files to open/read/execute as well as where to write new files.

You can of course also use a fully qualified file with directory path on the SPOOL command.

```
SQLcl: Release 19.2.1 Production on Thu Aug 15 09:07:50 2019

Copyright (c) 1982, 2019, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Last Successful login time: Thu Aug 15 2019 09:07:55 -04:00

Connected to:
Oracle Database 18c Enterprise Edition Release 18.0.0.0.0 - Production
Version 18.3.0.0.0


SQL> help cd
CD
---

 Changes path to look for script at after startup. 
(show SQLPATH shows the full search path currently: 
- CD current directory setting set by last cd command 
- baseURL (url for subscripts) 
- topURL (top most url when starting script) 
- Last Node opened (i.e. file in worksheet) 
- Where last script started 
- Last opened on sqlcl path related file chooser 
- SQLPATH setting 
- "." if in SQLDeveloper UI (included in SQLPATH in command line (sdsql))
). 
SQL>
```

Answer (score 0):

I just discovered that sqlplus always writes to the current working directory unless you give it a fully qualified filename to write to. So if you do a CD Your_Directory and after you run a script with SQLPLUS, it spools in the directory you moved just before!